# Specified argument was out of the range of valid values

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, managed-metadata-service

The following code generates "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values"

```
 TaxonomySession session = new TaxonomySession(site);

 TermStore termStore = session.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"];
```

I have added the onlogged user and the user which the application pool uses to "Managed Metadata Service" and all other Services on "Manage service applications" by choosing them and click on Permissions on ribbon and check Full control, but still session.TermStores.Count is 0. I can go to the managed metadata service and see all groups and terms.

Comment: The right index to use to access the TermStore is the proxy name probably `"Managed Metadata Service Proxy"`, but that wont help you until you get TermStore attached/running.

How to do you access the Managed Metadata through Central Admin or through Site Settings? Are you sure that Web App is connected to the Managed Metadata?

Comment: I am so sorry it was my mistake, I accessed the MMS last week and now when I test and access MMS through Central Admin it says:

The Managed Metadata Service or Connection is currently not available. The Application Pool or Managed Metadata Web Service may not have been started. Please Contact your Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following PowerShell to find out what the name is of your TermStore

```
asnp Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$tx = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site http://<yoursiteurl>
$tx.TermStores | ft
```

This should list all TermStores available for the MMS SA connected to the Site Coll (for which you provides the URL in the second line)

Comment: It generates following, which seems there is one:

DefaultLanguage   : 1033
Id                : 33ac140c-73e3-458c-b31f-aa5eb86a834b
Name              : Managed Metadata Service
WorkingLanguage   : 1033
Groups         : {System, Webbplatssamling - rkdhs-u}
ContentTypePublishingHub: 
IsOnline         : True
KeywordsTermSet    : Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TermSet
Languages          : {1033}
OrphanedTermsTermSet : Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TermSet
SystemGroup              : Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.Group
TermStoreAdministrators  : {}